# Raspberry Pi 4 doesn't boot when attaching camera

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I am having problem connecting the camera module to my Raspberry Pi 4. The PI is working just fine, but when I attach the camera to the module, it just doesn't boot.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a successfully booting system then after physically connecting the camera it will not boot?

First, double check the camera is connected properly. Meaning the blue side of the connections are facing the right way (i.e. blue side facing the USB ports on the RPi itself and facing the front of the camera on the camera module connection). [A quick search found this post containing pictures](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/16021420-how-to-install-use-the-raspberry-pi-camera), that is usually the issue. If that fails, consider options within the config.txt file on the /boot partition. [Reference for config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/README.md).

One of the config options that gets added automatically when adding the camera interface via raspi-config is `start_x=1` [Camera entries within config.txt are described here](https://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Camera). Be sure that you have enough memory configured (i.e. `gpu_mem=128`, though increasing that is probably a good idea if you're doing a lot with the GPU (motion detection, etc.). But the physical connection is most likely the culprit.